# How to handle the bits in an array of bytes in python to derive integer, string and float values using hex conversion

Tags: python, string, integer, byte, bit

Read input bytes from a binary file and convert the bytes to the corresponding hex value to derive the final integer, string and float values.

Tried reading the input binary file containing the bytes into an array of bytes and then processed the array values to derive the integer, string and float values.

Comment: Please show, as opposed to describe, what you tried.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want, but I think you will want to use [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#examples).

Comment: Please follow [ask].

Comment: While for integers endianness and size in bytes is required, floats have far more options, for a start look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).

Answer (score -1):

The byte level programming may require special library and syntax in python.

Comment: This looks like an assembly language solution ported to Python; I would start from scratch after having looked at the struct unit as recommended in a comment to the question.